# Nutrient depletion model and a logistic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

Show that the equation $ \frac{dN}{dt} = k(C_0 - \alpha N)N$ can be written in the form $ \frac{dN}{dt} = r(1 - \frac{N}{B} )N$ and interpret r and B.

Where $r=C_0 k $ and $ B = \frac{C_0}{ \alpha}$

Also show that as t approaches infinity, the population density approaches B.

I understand that this is a simple logistic equation, but so far the variables and how to properly interpret them has been throwing me off.

Comment: You might think of $B$ as a maximum carrying capacity because, when $N$ is close to $B$, $1-N/B$ (and therefore $dN/dt$ is close to zero. Thus the population growth slows as $N$ gets close to $B$ and would (in principle) stop, if the population could ever reach $B$. The constant $r$ is just a growth rate.

Comment: Even the rewriting escapes you? Sorry but *this* escapes me...